# How to use "window.open" in iOS for js command?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, appery.io

I am using Appery.io app builder and my app is JQM with v5.3 libraires version

I have to js code in click event and run in Android but not in iOS.

I tried this and the same result. Anything argument in window.open run in Andorid but not in IOS (mail, https…).

window.open("tel:+34607507097");

window.location.href = 'tel:+34607507097';

Any suggestions . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could I ask you to check if the in-app browser is enabled under **App settings > Cordova Plugins** and then check out this code:

```
if (window.cordova) {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open("tel:+34607507097", '_system');
}
```